# Wrong placement of divs on browser start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript/jquery to place a bunch of divs inside a bigger div:

```
this.inputArea.append(newItem);
```

this.inputArea is the jquery object of the container div and newItem is the corresponding object of the div being placed. Due to requirements the exact position of the div must be manually set, which is done with

```
newItem.offset({top: this.droppableOffsetTop+topOffset, left:this.droppableOffsetLeft+leftOffset});
```

I won't bore you with the exact calculations for the coords; suffice it to say they are based on this.inputArea.offset() plus where the new item is supposed to be within it. This code places a number of divs next to each other and runs right after the page has finished loading.

This works as intended with one exception. When the browser first loads the page all the divs are placed in random places all over the page, inside and outside their intended container. I've tested this in Firefox and Chrome and it happens in both. Refreshing the tab fixes the issue. Opening it in a second tab shows everything working fine. For added strangeness when I do "Inspect Element" in firefox, it immediately places them where they should be as if it was caught with its hand in the cookie jar.

Here is the proper placement:
[image]

And this is what I get:
[image]

For debugging purposes I outputted the calculated coords in the console and they are always the same, so the code works fine, it's just that two different browsers have some bizarre problem with placing divs the very first time they load.

Does anyone have any idea what this is? I haven't posted the full code since it's inside a complicated structure, but I may try to make a simple version for display if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this was happening, but I replaced

```
newItem.offset({top: this.droppableOffsetTop+topOffset, left:this.droppableOffsetLeft+leftOffset});
```

with (roughly) the following:

```
newItem.css('top', topOffset + 'px');
newItem.css('left', leftOffset + 'px');
```

and now it works.

Oh well.